# Численное решение уравнения движения python

Tags: python, математика

имеется следующее уравнение:

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть начальные условия x = -2, v = 0. Необходимо найти t, за которое x обнулится.
Я использовал примитивный способ, при котором считается, что за малый промежуток времени Δt скорость постоянна, тогда Δx += v * Δt. Таким способом можно найти решение t, но точность не очень хорошая.

Далее, я захотел выразить dt и посчитать интеграл и получил это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я более - менее знаком с методами численного интегрирования, но как считать интеграл с двойным дифференциалом не понятно.

Можете ли Вы мне что - то посоветовать с математикой или какие - нибудь функции численного интегрирования в python?

Comment: Гм. Знаете что, вы бы немного с дифференциальным анализом познакомились. Брать корень в такой ситуации — это что-то особенного :) А вообще, есть такой хороший метод Рунге-Кутта...

Comment: Если уж очень хочется немного преобразовать — см. https://i122.fastpic.org/big/2023/0604/2c/1c8473373e9dd5fa74cceb44d272b22c.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Кратко: никогда. Ни при каком t>=0 x не станет нулевым.

Почему? Потому что начальное x меньше нуля. Ускорение тоже меньше нуля по той же причине. Скорость при отрицательном ускорении тоже становится отрицательной. С течением времени ускорение стремится к нулю, скорость приобретает постоянное отрицательное значение, так что...

График решения имеет примерно такой вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если немного подумаете, то увидите, что и при t<0 x никогда не станет нулевым. Пусть это будет для вас домашним заданием...